# display related field based on textbox id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.textboxfor, editorformodel

I have two textboxes

```
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Voyage_ID, new{id="VID"})<br /></div>


<div>@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Arrived, new { @id = "arrived",})</div>
```

The first is updated dynamically from json based on the selected index of a dropdownlist. In the same manner, I wish to display the second field (and many more other fields that are) associated with the id captured in VID .

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery .change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#VID').change(function(){
       var currentValue = $(this).val(); //get current value of the input
       //here comes your logic
    });
})
```

Comment: I got that part down, but how do I actually push back the corresponding data of a field (like in the example above) whose (id=arrived) for the VID selected to the VIEW?

Comment: view renders on the server. javascript code executes on client. The code that i posted executes on client side when VID value changes. There is no such a thing "push back to VIEW"

Comment: ok. noted. is there a way to use the VID posted to the view, pass it back to the server, which would return the related data?

Comment: When you post your form back to the server you will get the value of VID together with all other inputs

Comment: nope... there is nothing telling the other fields (like arrived) which row it should return (the ID of which is VID). how do i get that?